# Discord API: How to Block a Specific Discord Channel?

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

I did a lot of research on how to block a channel from using commands, like Rythm's blackslist, but I didn't find it, could someone help me?

Comment: Why not blacklist the bot from reading and sending message in that channel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concept of a "channel blacklist" for commands lives entirely outside of the Discord API. There's no way to have the bot tell Discord to stop receiving messages for a channel (aside from, of course, editing the channel's permission overrides to deny the bot permissions to see the channel).

However, this is a very simple task regardless. You undoubtedly have a message handler of some sort. Something that looks like this:

```
client.on('message', message => {

  //check commands and stuff

});
```

If you want your bot to ignore a channel, it's the same thing as just not running your message handler in those channels. A naive implementation would be something like this:

```
client.on('message', message => {
  if(client.blacklist.includes(message.channel.id)) return;      

  //check commands and stuff

});
```

Of course, you may prefer to use a Map or a database call instead of just some array, and those options would be better for sure. But this is the basic pattern you need.